unmount and safely remove hard disk
I have been unmounting disk for quite sometime in my daily usage, and then doing 'safely remove drive'. It usually takes about a boring 30 s to 1 min or longer depending on the amount of documents/executions I've done in relation to the hard disk.
Until today, when I did 'safely remove drive' and it just powered down in like 3 seconds.
Question is what goes behind in unmounting process and should I be doing it or should I just do 'safely remove drive'.
I checked few answers and from what i read, 'safely remove drive' was designed for HDDs and other similar accessories.

On the operating system side this includes ensuring that no process is using the drive, then requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable storage.
